# Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade boost 1.46 to 1.60

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boost

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to upgrade boost to 1.60.
I did like this to uninstall 1.46 from my system

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-dev   
sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-all-dev
```

And after that when I do below command to see the version, it still says I have 1.49

```
cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"
//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_46_1" .
```

I want to delete or upgrade this boost to boost 1.60 version.
Someone knows how?
thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp` ? That will tell you what package contains it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick ~$ dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
libboost1.46-dev: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Do you know how to upgrade it?

Comment: I'd recommend removing the old version and compiling 1.60 from source. https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.60.0/ http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install

Answer (score 1):

> @MarkPlotnick ~$ dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp libboost1.46-dev: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp

There you go. You forgot to remove the actual packages. Perhaps

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will be enough, unless you have "manually" selected the non-generic packages. In which case you could do something like

```
sudo apt-get remove 'libboost-.*'
```

Be sure to carefully review the list of lirbaries slated for removal. If anything else on your system requires it, it might get removed as well. TO be somewhat more safe, start with e.g.

```
sudo apt-get remove 'libboost-.*-dev'
```

Comment: Oh yeah, and just compile the new version from source. If you want to be "quick"/"lazy" about it here's a trick to ensure most dependencies: `apt-get build-dep libboost-all-dev`